# What is this type of method overriding called in Java?

Tags: java, overriding, anonymous-inner-class

I'm relatively new to Java and I'm using a new API. I came across this method override and I'm not sure what this is called:

```
public void exampleMethod() {
    Button loginButton = new Button("login"){
       public void onSubmit(){
          //submit code here
       }
    };
}
```

From what I understand, this is overriding the onSubmit method of the Button class. I've never come across this type of overriding before. Is there a specific name for it? I want to read up more about it but I can't find it. All my searches so far result to regular method overriding by creating a new class, which is what I'm already familiar with.

I'd appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Great question... and it's the kind of thing that's very difficult to look up in a reference! +1 Thankfully, as I attempted to ask the same Q on SO, it found your Q for me.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

That's an [anonymous inner class](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html).

In the example above instead of creating a `private class` that extends `Button` we create an subclass of Button and provide the implementation of the overridden method in line with the rest of the code.

As this new class is created on the fly it has no name, hence **anonymous**.  As it's defined inside another class it's an anonymous **inner** class.

It can be a very handy shortcut, especially for `Listener` classes, but it can make your code hard to follow if you get carried away and the in line method definitions get too long.

Answer (score 13):

That's an [*anonymous inner class*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/innerclasses.html). Basically it creates a new class which derives from the specified one (`Button` in this case, although you can use the same technique to implement interfaces) and overrides appropriate methods. It can contain other methods as well, but they'd only be available within that class.

The class has access to final local variables within the same method, and if you're writing an instance method it has an implicit reference to `this` as well (so you can call other methods in your "main" class).

Comment: Thank you. I searched inner method, but didn't think of it as an inner class, much less an anonymous inner class. 

Off to read about them I go!

Answer (score 7):

That is an anonymous inner class.

More info: [Anonymous classes](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/anonymousclasses.html)